# calculate constants $a$ and $c$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

The height in metres of Jack's beanstalk $t$ weeks after it was planted is given by $$h = a(e^{ct} -1)$$

Its heights at the end of the first two weeks were $10cm$ and $50cm$.

Calculate the constants $a$ and $c$

I can't seem to get the correct answer using simultaneous equations. How should I be going about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you substitute the two constraints in, we get
$$
0.5 = a \left(e^{2c}-1\right)\\
0.1 = a \left(e^c-1\right).
$$
It may be easier to see the next step if we give $e^c$ some name, say $d$; with this choice of parameters, the equations above become
$$
0.5 = a \left(d^2 - 1 \right)\\
0.1 = a \left(d-1\right).
$$
Factoring the first equation gives the pair
$$
\begin{align}
0.5 &= a\left(d-1\right)\left(d+1\right)\\
0.1 &= a\left(d-1\right),
\end{align}
$$
from which it should be straightforward to find $d$, followed by $a$ and $c$.

(It's not actually necessary to replace $e^c$ with $d$, but it helps motivate factoring $e^{2c}-1$ into $\left(e^c-1\right)\left(e^c+1\right)$.)

Comment: thank you, this helped! I was rewriting both equations in terms of c and then doing simultaneous equations.. so I ended up with $$ln(e^{2c} - 1) -ln(e^{c} - 1) = ln5$$ which I believe I wrongly worked out to be $2c -c = ln5$.